# WPF как получить список всех привязок у данного элемента

Tags: c#, wpf

Разъясните пожалуйста привязку в WPF:

- после привязки очередного свойства (например св/ва Text элемента TextBlock) где-то должна сохранятся эта привязка, в каком-то словаре? где находится этот словарь? т.е. у каждого элемента ( допустим в окне Window) есть свой локальный словарь привязок его свойств или есть какой-то один глобальный словарь привязок отдельного Window или глобальный словарь всего приложения?
- как получить список всех привязок (список всех привязанных свойств)  у элемента?

Спасибо!

Comment: За контроль привязки овечает класс `Binding`, никаких словарей нет, есть только созданные экземпляры `Binding`, которые внутри себя хранят и используют всю информацию о привязках. А зачем вам это? Получить ифнормацию о привязке можно из свойств класса `Binding` - [свойства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding?view=net-5.0#properties).

Comment: зачем - разбираюсь с привязкой в WPF.
Да, можно получить привязку конкретного свойства,
но, получается нет никакого списка/словаря привязок у  элемента 
и если, вдруг, я захочу просмотреть все привязки у элемента, мне надо будет получить все свойства этого элемента и проверять каждое свойство по отдельности?

Comment: Типа того, но вам не должно хотеться смотреть в привязки свойства, в этом просто нет никакого смысла. А так, смотрите в [методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement?view=net-5.0) `FrameworkElement`, они позволяют управлять привязками и доступны у каждого контрола.